# Is it possible to redirect to view from a non-controller class in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Was working on logging using NLOG and there is separate class @ global level from where logging happens. Per requirement, have to redirect to "Error" view (`Error.cshtml`) from that class after logging is over.

But it's a non-controller class and hence can't use usual methods like `RedirectToAction()` or simply `return View("Error")`.

Is there any way possible of doing that? I tried `Response.Redirect()` but doesn't do anything.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/Help/Error",true);
```

`Error.cshtml` is a plain HTML file with text like *There is some error ... please contact admin* which is present under `Views/Shared/*` folder.

Logging class is present in a separate folder say `logging` under root folder.

On every call to Action method if any exception occurs then the logger gets invoked automatically which does it's stuff of logging and finally should redirect to the error view.

Comment: Need to provide more information about how you are catching errors.  What the code path is that gets you to this logging code.

Comment: @AaronLS, included those info as well. See edit in post.

Comment: Is there a reason you want that code in your external class ? can't you move the code from that class to the `OnException` event in your (base) controller ?

Comment: @Shyju, yes may be there is and it's existing one ... moreover not in a position to move it to base controller. But from your comment sounds like there is no way of getting this done. Which sounds bit logical as well. let know.

Comment: What @Shyju is referring to is having global error handling code that catches any errors, then logs them via your logging library, and then redirects to a error page.  Results from a quick google search: https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging.

Comment: @BrendanGreen, yep got it and edited comment as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own base controller and handle the exceptions in the onexception event

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
       //Do your logging
       // and redirect / return error view
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        // If the exception occured in an ajax call. Send a json response back
        // (you need to parse this and display to user as needed at client side)
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"]=="XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new { Error = true, Message = filterContext.Exception.Message }
            };
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500; // Set as needed
        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error.cshtml" }; 
            //Assuming the view exists in the "~/Views/Shared" folder
        }
    }
}
```

Now for your other controllers, inherit from this bascontroller.

```
public class ProductsController : BaseController 
{
   public ActionResult Die()
   {
     throw new Exception("I lost!");
   }
}
```

If you want to do a redirect (a new GET call) to your Error action method, you can replace the ViewResult with a `RedirectToRouteResult`.

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary {
                                               {"controller", "Home"}, {"action", "Error"}
                                              };
```

Comment: Sorry but not in a position to change code cause it's existing code but definitely can help other though ... nice suggestion.

Comment: @Rahul All you said was "the logger gets invoked automatically" so we're going to recommend solutions in the absence of that information.

Comment: @AaronLS, I will add info about that soon in post. it's written by someone else long back and I don't understand MVC much

Comment: Sorry for long delay in appreciating for the nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how the logging code is called automatically "the logger gets invoked automatically".  So I'm going to recommend a HandleErrorAttribute.  This requires you have a Error.cshtml in your shared views folder, but you could specify a different view in filterContext.Result

```
public class CustomErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute 
{

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;// This causes the webconfig httpErrors section to be ignored, since we are handling the exception
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

        //... log error

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.ClearContent();// Removes partially rendered content

        // just information to be passed in the view model, this does NOT define which view is displayed next.  It tells us where the error came from.
        var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);
        // This presents an error page view.  By default if a View is not passed to the Attribute, then this is Error.cshtml in Shared.
        filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = View,  // View & Master are parameters from the attribute e.g. [ErrorAttribute(View="OtherErrorView")], by default the view is the "Error.cshtml" view
            MasterName = Master,
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<HandleErrorInfo>(model),
            TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
        };

        filterContext.Exception = null;


    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for long delay in appreciating for the nice answer.